# Spark structured streaming: why java code uses DataSet and scala uses DataFrame type?

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

Hi I'm just reading offical document of spark structured streaming: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example

Its sample code of java uses DataFrame and introduces DataFrame as the basic type for structured streaming, but meanwhile the sibling java code uses Dataset as data type. I'm just wondering, as long as spark/scala is running on jvm, shouldn't both scala and java use the same data type to represent?

Or DataFrame is in fact a kind of Dataset, somehow?

Hope to get your explanations of this question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DataFrame` is, indeed, a special case of `DataSet` - `DataSet[Row]`, where `Row` is a mostly generic type defined [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row). `DataFrame` as a term and a type predates the `DataSet` API, and its usage as an alias for `DataSet[Row]` is more or less a compatibility feature in Scala Spark. A full explanation of the differences, such as they are, is availabe [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes).